# Identify all instances of a set where any one instance of the set is paired with a specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, countif

I am trying to highlight data by row based on an a ref number. The system I pull the report from creates a new event and thus new row item for each action. So every time it breaches or is achieved a new line is created and I am only interested in weather at some point in its life it has breached and care less about how many times.I have got the logic working for the conditonal statemnt but wondered if there was a way to cycle through the rows like I would if I was using PHP. For instance

```
While(row){
    if(row= "Breached"){
    //do some stuff     
    }
}
```

The desired end result being that I have a store with list of all the INC's that have breached but I need to know if there is dynamic way of searching rows

```
1   INC123  BREACHED
2   INC123  ACHIEVED
3   INC123  BREACHED
4   INC321  ACHIEVED
5   INC321  ACHIEVED
6   INC999  BREACHED
7   INC999  BREACHED
8   INC111  ACHIEVED
9   INC111  ACHIEVED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is all instances of a specific INCnnn to be identified where any one of the specific INCnnn is in the same row as "BREACHED" then Conditional Formatting would do this, say as below assuming your data starts with `1` in A1 and is in three columns.

Select the column to be highlighted (ie `B`) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,C:C,"BREACHED")>0
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting of choice, OK, OK.